# TSQL- Rearrange sql job step order in code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

I have a few SQL maintenance jobs that have upwards of 50 job steps. Occasionally, there is a need to add a step or two to one of these monstrous SQL jobs. The issue I have is that I prefer each step be in alphabetical order (if possible), but to accomplish this I need to press the up arrow countless times and wait for the screen to refresh. I looked into the sp_update jobs procedures and they don't seem to address this issue.

Is there a way that this can be accomplished in code?

Comment: So none of these jobs depend on another one?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :( I looked into cascading them in a way. I could always just leave them in disarray . . alphabetically but this would drive me nuts. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documented procedure in TSQL or API in SMO to change the order of job steps. If you re-order job steps in SSMS and generate the action script, you'll see that it deletes and re-creates all the job steps in the new order.

The most obvious solution is to develop your own script or tool to re-order the steps by dropping and re-creating them, i.e. re-create the SSMS functionality but optimized for your own needs.

A last resort would be to update `sysjobsteps.step_id` to modify the execution order, but modifying system tables directly is definitely not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Pond! I was under that impression to begin with after my Google search yielded zero results. I'd craft one by hand but don't have the time. +1 Wish list  :)

Answer (score 6):

I found this question while trying to re-order steps without clearing them all out and re-adding them.

To resolve the situation, I have a three-step process:
(Assuming there is only one step out of order, or that the existing steps are all in alpha-order)

1) If necessary, Delete the step you want to re-order. (You should use a select against msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps if you need any existing values)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobstep @job_id = @YOURJOBID, @step_id = @OUTOFORDERSTEPID
```

2) Use comparison to get the position that your new step should be in.

```
@newStepPosition = SELECT MIN(step_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps WHERE job_id = @YOURJOBID AND step_name > N'YOURNEWSTEPNAME'
```

3) Simply add the job step, specifying the position. All existing steps will shuffle down. e.g. Inserting at 3 will push 3 to 4, 4 to 5, etc.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@YOURJOBID, @step_name=N'YOURNEWSTEPNAME',
  @step_id=@newStepPosition,
  etc...
```

Tested with MS SQL Server 2008 R2. Hope that helps anyone else looking at this.

Comment: Confirmed that inserting shuffles the rest down.  Inserting into step 1 also sets the job to start from the newly inserted step, which is more than what ssms did for me through the wizard.